# Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset() gives different value for different years

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

On my Chrome console it runs like this

```
new Date(Date.UTC(1942, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)).getTimezoneOffset()
//-120
new Date(Date.UTC(1922, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)).getTimezoneOffset()
//-60
new Date(Date.UTC(1912, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)).getTimezoneOffset()
//0
new Date(Date.UTC(1902, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)).getTimezoneOffset()
//-9
```

Does anyone have any explanation there? Especially that `-9` is really confusing

Comment: In both Firefox and Chrome, I'm getting 240 / 300 / 300 / 300. That 240 might (imo) be from summer time/winter time?

Comment: What is your Time Zone? What happens when you put in `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()` ? I am seeing a reasonable result when doing all of those statements as well, so this might be related to your browser / time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those values are all correct for France.

[Prior to 1911 France used PMT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris?year=1900) (Paris Mean Time) which was 9 minutes ahead of UTC (offset `-9`).

From March 1911 through 1915 they used UTC (offset `0`).

From 1916 onward, the country has had daylight savings time and alternated from UTC to UTC+1 (offset `-60`), but in 1940 they moved forward one more hour and now alternate from UTC+1 to UTC+2 (offset `-120`).

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Thank you, 9:21 to be more precisely :)

Comment: @Jiqnpqn—maybe, but the value returned by *getTimezoneOffset* only has a resolution of minutes.

Comment: @RobG  --- yes but `new Date(Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))` here gives me `Mon Jan 01 1900 00:09:21 GMT+0009 (Central European Standard Time)` in chrome. so it's kinda ambiguous

Comment: @Jiqnpqn—I guess you just found a way of getting second resolution. :-)